# Chen ERD Relationship Attributes

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd, conceptual

[image: chen database erd diagram]

This is a portion of a Gaming Company Chen diagram that I need to convert to a database.  How do I know which entity will get the attributes LastPlayed and CreatedOn?  I feel like I could make a case for either entity.  It could be the LastPlayed and Created on of the Account or the Character. Is there a rule for this? TIA

Comment: Where are you stuck in what published presentation of what design method? Why are you wondering how to do something that you aren't doing because the method says to do it? PS "feel" is unhelpful. PS Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The attributes you show belong to the relationship, and not either of the entities.  In this case, practically speaking implementation would make them part of the (N) side of the relationship, that is, the Character entity.

The distinction between entity-attributes and relation-attributes only really matters for many-to-many relations that have to be implemented by converting the relation into its own table.

Comment: Attributes have to go somewhere when you create the table though?  Why would they go to the N side?

Comment: @ITGirl because you need N of them.  If you have (1) parent row and (N) child rows, then there are (N) relationship links from the child rows to the parent row.  So attributes attached to the relation would, in this case, have (N) instances.  Because of this, it is most convenient to implement this by moving them to the child rows which already have the same cardinality.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thank you for explaining.